# AngularJs post request getting error

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am trying to do a `POST` request to a login api through angular js .

```
<form method="post" ng-submit="doLogin()">
      <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Username</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="loginData.user_mail">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Password</span>
          <input type="password" ng-model="loginData.password">
        </label>
        <label class="item">
          <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit" >{{loginTxt}}</button>
        </label>
      </div>
      </form>
```

Controller.js

```
$scope.doLogin=function(){
     $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : 'http://examplemns.com/customer/api/v1/login/login',
          data    : $scope.loginData, //forms user object
          timeout:20000
         })
         .success(function(response){
             
              alert(JSON.stringify(response));
           })
           .error(function(err){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
                alert("Network error");
                
             });
         }
```

But i will get `invalid username` response even if the username and password is correct.
I checked the api through postman plugin its working fine,but when comes with angular i will get invalid.

Here is the sample input

```
user_mail:avm@gmail.com
password:123456
```

When try this input with postman plugin i will get the correct response

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "message": "Done",
  "data": {
    "name": "A.V.M TOURIST HOME",
    "username": "avm@gmail.com",
    "id": "37",
    "key": "cos4ok88woo0kcw40cog0s4gg4skogscso8848ok"
  }
}
```

but when trying through the angularjs post i with the same input i will get this response

```
{"status":0,"message":"Invalid username"}
```

Please help me:(

**UPDATE**

I need to transform my  data to application/x-www-form-urlencoded rather than json (from comments) for that i am used this way.

```
var data= {user_mail:$scope.loginData.user_mail,password:$scope.loginData.password};
$http({
              method  : 'POST',
              url     : 'http://examplemns.com/customer/api/v1/login/login',
              data    : data, 
              timeout:20000
             })
             .success(function(response){
                 
                  alert(JSON.stringify(response));
               })
               .error(function(err){
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
                    alert("Network error");
                    
                 });
```

But again i will get the same

Screenshot of request and response from the postman

[image]

Comment: can you show us either a screenshot or the textual version of your postman request ?

Comment: Does postman send the data as json like angular will ?

Comment: you can get the textual version by clicking on 'generate' at the top right of postman window

Comment: The response from the postman is already included in my question

Comment: response yes, but I am interested in the request

Comment: @Paqman post man send data as form-data

Comment: ahh but that explains it , you need to set $http to send as form data too

Comment: check that link http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2615-posting-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: @sam do you mean the genrate code option??

Comment: @sam how can i use it my case?

Comment: You'll need to transform your data to application/x-www-form-urlencoded rather than json. Check the transformRequest and the serializeData function from the @sam 's link.

Comment: I can't find  a valid solution from that link

Comment: could you provide the error log ?? and what are the supported content-type of your web service ?

Comment: I am going to ask a probably stupid question but... are you really sending 'user_mail:avm@gmail.com' or are you sending 'user_mail:"avm@gmail.com"' ? (un your JSON with angular)

Comment: I am sending "user_email" :avm@gmail.com

Comment: well try with "user_email" :"avm@gmail.com"

Comment: @sam how  to  that

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    $scope.loginData = {};
    $scope.doLogin=function(){

         $http({
              method  : 'POST',
              url     : 'http://examplemns.com/customer/api/v1/login/login',
              data    : $scope.loginData, //forms user object ,
              headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

             })
             .success(function(response){
                  console.log(response);
             })
             .error(function(err){
                    console.log(err);
              });
            }
```

**OR**

```
$scope.loginData = {};
var data = $scope.loginData;
$http.post('/examplemns.com/customer/api/v1/login/login', data).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

**ALSO TRY THIS**

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="user_mail">
  <input type="password" ng-model="password">

  var data = {};
  data.user_mail = $scope.user_mail;
  data.password = $scope.password;

  $http.post('/examplemns.com/customer/api/v1/login/login',   data).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Comment: He needs to set as Form data instead of simple JSON object

Comment: `{"data":{"status":0,"message":"Invalid Username."},"status":200,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"http://smaplessss,com/customer/api/v1/login/login","data":{"user_mail":"avm@gmail.com","password":"123456"},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":"OK"}`

Comment: I will get this on successcallback

Comment: you receive on sucesscalback??have your request url server is working?

Comment: yes we really need the postman request to compare with the angular config

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad yes url server is working and i will get the response in successcalllback

Comment: @BlessanKurien your postmen url and your angular `$http` url is different

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad  actullay url's are correct,i can't show the orginal link here.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following line:

```
data    : $scope.loginData, //forms user object
```

to:

```
data    : JSON.stringify($scope.loginData), //forms user object
```